# running multiple Spark jobs on a Mesos cluster

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I would like to run multiple spark jobs on my Mesos cluster, and have all spark jobs share the same spark framework. Is this possible? 
I have tried running the MesosClusterDispatcher and have the spark jobs connect to the dispatcher, but each spark job launches its own "Spark Framework" (I have tried running both client-mode and cluster-mode). 
Is this the expected behaviour? 
Is it possible to share the same spark-framework among multiple spark jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal and it's the expected behaviour.

In Mesos as far as I know, SparkDispatcher is in charge of allocate resources for your Spark Driver which will act as a framework. Once Spark driver has been allocated, it is responsible for talk to Mesos and accept offers to allocate the executors where tasks will be executed.

Comment: When running in "client-mode" there is no SparkDispatcher and the driver interacts directly with Mesos. So why is the dispatcher needed in cluster mode?

Comment: Suggest you have a look at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I am familiar with the documentation but how does this answer my question> Are you referring to the "recovery state" that is written into Zookeeper by the dispatcher?

Comment: You asked: why is the dispatcher needed in cluster mode? and the docs (that you say you're familiar with) explain that in the Cluster mode section, no?